# do MobileVLCKit support Airplay option in iOS?

Tags: objective-c

I have implemented VCL to play the live streaming video and Now I want to play it on apple TV by airplay option on my streaming screen..

Can you pls help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By question its not clear what you mean by implementing VLC. Apple provided framework to stream live video ([AVPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller?changes=_3&language=objc)). Which supports Picture-in-picture and airplay.

For making things more clear please elaborate, what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: thanks for the reply Manish. I'm using RTMP Url for live video but AVPlayer is not supportable for RTMP that why now I'm using VCLKit, now I want airplay option on my live screen to share on Apple TV..

Answer (score 0):

Support for AirPlay will be available in libvlc and VLCKit 4.0 next year. It will allow you play anything from any source on Apple TV and if needed, will convert the media on-the-fly. Thus, AirPlay support will match what's possible with Chromecast right now.

With VLCKit 3, there is no good way to do it. You could do Display Mirroring, but this would have a bad impact on performance and video quality. Audio-only output via AirPlay / RAOP will just work fine and quality is good. It even supports multichannel now.